# What is the difference between two function spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $P$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure and $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be the corresponding function space where $\Omega$ is the domain and $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{F}$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra, then what is the differences and connections between the two spaces: $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{C}, P)$?

The reason I am asking this question is that during the proof to show the existence of conditional expectation using the Riesz representation theorem, it is claimed that $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{C}, P)$ to be a closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. I understand that a function $f$ that is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable is not necessarily $\mathcal{C}$-measurable, but the other direction does not necessarily hold, but is there any other more intuitive properties that distinguish functions in $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{C}, P)$ from functions in $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Is a $\mathcal{C}$-measurable function $\mathcal{F}$-measurable? How about the other way around?

Comment: @ian yes to the first and no to the second. They're both immediate to prove using the definition of measurability :-)

Comment: @Ian Yes you are right, the other direction does not hold, but is there other more intuitive properties that can be used to distinguish functions in these two spaces?

Comment: That's about all that there really is to be said for completely general $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{F}$. The interesting thing is particular cases, such as when $\mathcal{C}$ is an element of a filtration and $\mathcal{F}$ is some underlying "large" $\sigma$-algebra. Then $\mathcal{C}$ describes information that can be obtained by only observing your process up to a certain finite time.

Comment: @Ian OK, that makes sense to me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is completely for your intuition. Many things I am about to say are imprecise and in certain cases flat out wrong. This is why we use mathematics, to precisely capture what we intuit.

Think of $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ as containing information. The probabilist language is built around this analogy. Since $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathcal{F}$, we say $\mathcal{F}$ has more information (sets) than $\mathcal{C}$ does. Then what does it mean for $X$ to be $\mathcal{F}$ measurable? It means that if you have the information in $\mathcal{F}$, then you can measure the true value of $X$, otherwise there is some randomness in $X$ that stops you from knowing its true value. If $Y$ is $\mathcal{C}$ measurable, you don't need as much information to measure $Y$. If two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G}$ are independent, it means the information they contain have nothing to do with each other in the sense that telling me the outcome of an $\mathcal{H}$-measurable experiment won't affect your beliefs (probabilities) for the outcome of any $\mathcal{G}$-measurable experiment.

$L^2$ just adds an extra integrability condition. That is, $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ are both sets of square integrable random variables, where in the first case you can determine their value with all the information in $\mathcal{F}$, and in the second you only need the information in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Thanks! The analogy here is great!

Comment: @HanZhao Also note that this "information" concept is rather precisely captured by the notion of conditional expectation. With no information, the conditional expectation is just the expectation (you know nothing about fluctuations at all). With all the information, the conditional expectation is just the r.v. itself. With *partial* information you may have a pretty good idea of the r.v. but not know it quite exactly, so $E[X|\mathcal{A}]$ can be random but not exactly equal to $X$.

Comment: @HanZhao On top of that, there is a theorem that says that if $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, then there is a Borel measurable function $\phi$ such that $X=\phi(Y)$. Thus "knowing $Y$ exactly tells you $X$" in this sense (if only you could compute $\phi$).

Comment: @Ian I guess here the $\phi(Y)$ is exactly $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ which is a function of $Y$ right?

Comment: @HanZhao Eh it depends on your definitions. In the definitions I learned, $E[X|Y]$ is defined to be a shorthand for $E[X|\sigma(Y)]$, so some actual work is required to show that such a $\phi$ corresponds to it. But yes, either way, that is where $\phi$ comes from.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{F}$, then and $f$ is $\mathcal{C}$ measurable, then for every open $U\subset \mathbb R$, $f^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{F}$, so $f$ is also $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.  Further, since the integral of a measurable function depends only on the measure and not the $\sigma$-algebra (although the $\sigma$-algebra affects whether a function is measurable), we have that $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{C},P)$ is the intersection of $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ with the set of $\mathcal{C}$-measurable functions.